# I need to strip the class "touch" when delivering data to an excel sheet

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, excel

Here's my problem, all the data inside touch which is a select box is rendering inside excel and creating blanks.

[image]

```
<tr class="proj_rec" data-id="4">
            <td class="proj_id">
                4                    </td>
            <td>
                Music in the stores                    </td>
            <td class="edit">
                <select class="touch" style="display: none;">
                    <option value="13">Bloopers</option><option value="1">Customer Service</option><option value="2">DC</option><option value="3">Ecommerce</option><option value="4">Finance/Accounting</option><option value="5">Human Resources</option><option value="6">Inbound Logistics</option><option value="7">Information Systems</option><option value="14">Management</option><option value="8">Marketing</option><option value="9">Merchandising</option><option value="10">Property</option><option value="11">Rebuying</option><option value="12">Sales</option>                        </select>
                <span class="look">
                    Sales                        </span>
            </td>
            <td class="edit">
                <select class="touch" style="display: none;">
                    <option value="1">As is review</option><option value="2">Complete</option><option value="3">Development</option><option value="4">Implemented</option><option value="5">Not started</option><option value="6">To be design</option>                        </select>
                <span class="look">
                    As is review                        </span>
            </td>
            <td class="edit">
                <select class="touch" style="display: none;">
                    <option value="1"> Objective</option><option value="2"> People</option><option value="3"> Process</option><option value="4"> Systems</option>                        </select>
                <span class="look">
                     Process                        </span>
            </td>
```

I'm using this code to build the td classes

```
function back_to_look() {
$('td.editing ,td.edit.new').each(function() {
    $(this).children('.look').show();
    $(this).children('.touch').hide();
    if (!$(this).hasClass('edit')) {
        $(this).addClass('edit');
    }
    if ($(this).hasClass('editing')) {
        $(this).removeClass('editing');
    }
});
```

}

Here's what i'm using to pass my data into excel:

```
<td><input type="button" id="dlink" onclick="tableToExcel('project_table', 'W3C Example Table')" value="Export to Excel"></td>
            <a id="dlink"  style="display:none;"></a>

var tableToExcel = (function () {
        var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
        , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
        , base64 = function (s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
        , format = function (s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function (m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
        return function (table, name, filename) {
            if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
            var ctx = { worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML }
            document.getElementById("dlink").href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx));
            document.getElementById("dlink").download = filename;
            document.getElementById("dlink").click();

        }
    })()
```

---

```
  var tableToExcel = (function () {
   $('#clonedtable .touch').each(function(){
       $(this).parent().prepend($(this).val()); //if you want to keep the values.
   });
   $('#clonedtable .touch').remove();
   var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
        , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
        , base64 = function (s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
        , format = function (s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function (m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
        return function (table, name, filename) {
            if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)

            var ctx = { worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML }
            document.getElementById("dlink").href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx));
            document.getElementById("dlink").download = filename;
            document.getElementById("dlink").click();
   $('#clonedtable').remove(); 
    }
})()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can grab the values and prep-end them to the rows or just remove them completely before you convert the table to excel.

If you want to keep your table intact I would recommend cloning the table and then making the excel file out of the cloned table and afterwards deleting it.

It would look something like this

```
return function (table, name, filename) {
   $('#clonedtable .touch').each(function(){
       $(this).parent().prepend($(this).val()); //if you want to keep the values.
   });
   $('#clonedtable .touch').remove();
   .... //create the excel of the cloned table
   $('#clonedtable').remove(); 
    }
})()
```

**Update**
Try this instead.

```
var tableToExcel = (function () {
....
    return function (table, name, filename) {
        $('#'+table+' .touch').each(function(){
            $(this).parent().prepend($(this).val()); //if you want to keep the values.
        });
        $('#'+table+' .touch').remove();
        .... //create the excel of the cloned table
        $('#'+table).remove(); 
     }
})()
```

Comment: I'll give this a go right now. I'm going to wrap the jquery in it's own JS function and insert it above var ctx.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused, I tried this solution but maybe i have a syntax error.

Comment: I'll edit my question to show you what i've done.. it didn't work though.

Comment: I'll look at it tomorrow.. But on a quick glance I am not seeing anywhere where you are cloning the table...  I'll see if I can be of help tomorrow though.

Comment: @cook Check my update, Try moving all the code into your `return function` I also changed the code so that it will reference the table passed it it.

Comment: I'm testing right now, but when you say create the excel of the cloned table.. do you mean.. this line?   var ctx = { worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML }

Comment: It's really close but it's not delivering the data into excel properly and after i export to excel it's removing the table data on the UI side of things. super close to getting it to work though. Just a bit more help, hang in there with me please. =]

Comment: @cook `Update 2` uses a cloned table so that the table wont be removed on on the UI side of things.. As far as the excel not delivering the data properly you may need to experiment with it..  You can post a screen shot here so I can see what is happening as well.